# How to toggle a layer on/off using Google Maps API v3 and Fusion Tables?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to make a map with multiple fusion table layers. Each fusion table layer will show the number of cartel-related homicides in a particular year (including the sum of all years). Since each layer has the same geometry, I need to let the user view one layer at a time. Is there a way to toggle each layer on/off using a radio button? I've searched for tutorials or examples for a few hours and have come up empty, so I'm hoping someone here can help.

Here is a link to a copy of the map: https://mywebspace.wisc.edu/csterling/web/cartel%20map/index%20-%20practice.html

Here is the code (sorry about the formatting)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDRngi4TwTlx3r9zRXxIGzbSAq6OcEpxjA&sensor=false"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheet.css' />
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>

window.onload = function () {

    var oceanStyle = [
        {
         featureType: "ocean",
         stylers: [
            { saturation: -100 }
            ]
        },
        {
         featureType: "all",
         elementType: "labels",
         stylers: [
         { visibility: "off"}
         ]
         }

    ];

    var oceanMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(oceanStyle, 
        {name: "Grayscale"});


    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);

    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(24,-103),
        zoom: 5,
        //mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {                
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP,
            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, 'Grayscale']
            },

        panControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL

        }
        };                  

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mymap"), mapOptions);

    map.mapTypes.set('Grayscale',oceanMapType);
    map.setMapTypeId('Grayscale');

    var layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query:{
            select: 'unique_id',
            from: '3943497'
        },
        map: map

    });

        /*
    var layer2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({

        query:{
            select: 'unique_id',
            from: '3962564'         
        },
        map: map

    }); */



    }


</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='mymap'></div>
```

#

EDIT

#

Ok, I got it! Here's my code in case others are having the same question:

```
<html>

<head>

<!-- <script src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false' type='text/javascript'></script> -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDRngi4TwTlx3r9zRXxIGzbSAq6OcEpxjA&sensor=false"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='stylesheet.css' />
```

```
var map;

//var layArray = [];

var shownLayer;

var layer_sum;

var layer_2007;

var layer_2008;

var layer_2009;

var layer_2010;



function toggleLayer(this_layer){

    shownLayer.setMap(null);

    this_layer.setMap(map);

    shownLayer = this_layer;

    /*if ( this_layer.getMap() ) {

        this_layer.setMap(null);

    }else{

        this_layer.setMap(map);

    }*/ 

}



 window.onload = function () {



    var oceanStyle = [

        {

         featureType: "ocean",

         stylers: [

            { saturation: -100 }

            ]

        },

        {

         featureType: "all",

         elementType: "labels",

         stylers: [

         { visibility: "off"}

         ]

         }



    ];



    var oceanMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(oceanStyle, 

        {name: "Grayscale"});





    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);



    var mapOptions = {

        center: new google.maps.LatLng(24,-103),

        zoom: 6,

        //mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,

        mapTypeControl: true,

        mapTypeControlOptions: {                

            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP,

            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, 'Grayscale']

            },



        panControl: true,

        streetViewControl: false,

        zoomControl: true,

        zoomControlOptions: {

            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL



        }

        };                  



    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mymap"), mapOptions);



    map.mapTypes.set('Grayscale',oceanMapType);

    map.setMapTypeId('Grayscale');





    layer_sum = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({

        query:{

            select: 'unique_id',

            from: '3943497'

        },      



    }); 





    layer_2007 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({



        query:{

            select: 'unique_id',

            from: '3962564'         

        },          



    }); 



    layer_2008 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({



        query:{

            select: '2008',

            from: '3962469'

        },



    });



    layer_2009 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({



        query: {

            select: '2009',

            from: '3964318'             

        },

    });



    layer_2010 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({



        query: {

            select: '2010',

            from: '3964517'

        },

    });



    layer_sum.setMap(map);

    shownLayer = layer_sum;





    }





</script>

</head>

<body>    

  <div id='mymap'></div>    

  <div id='map-optionbar-r'>        

    Sum of Homicides<input name="layers" type="radio" value="layer_sum" onClick="toggleLayer(layer_sum);" checked><br />

    Homicides - 2007<input name="layers" type="radio" value="layer_2007" onClick="toggleLayer(layer_2007);"><br />

    Homicides - 2008<input name="layers" type="radio" value="layer_2008" onClick="toggleLayer(layer_2008);"><br />

    Homicides - 2009<input name="layers" type="radio" value="layer_2009" onClick="toggleLayer(layer_2009);"><br />

    Homicides - 2010<input name="layers" type="radio" value="layer_2010" onClick="toggleLayer(layer_2010);"><br />

  </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
toggleLayer(layer1);
// make sure your map is a global
function toggleLayer(this_layer)
{
   if( this_layer.getMap() ){
        this_layer.setMap(null);
   }else{
        this_layer.setMap(map);
   }
}
</head>
<body>
<br />
Layer 1<input name="layers" type="radio" value="layer1" onClick="toggleLayer(layer1);"><br />
Layer 2<input name="layers" type="radio" value="layer2" onClick="toggleLayer(layer2);"><br />
```

**UPDATED**

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
    var map, layer1, layer2;
  google.load("maps", "3", {other_params:"sensor=false"});
 window.onload = function () {

    var oceanStyle = [
        {
         featureType: "ocean",
         stylers: [
            { saturation: -100 }
            ]
        },
        {
         featureType: "all",
         elementType: "labels",
         stylers: [
         { visibility: "off"}
         ]
         }

    ];

    var oceanMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(oceanStyle, 
        {name: "Grayscale"});


    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);

    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(24,-103),
        zoom: 5,
        //mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {                
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP,
            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, 'Grayscale']
            },

        panControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL

        }
    };                  

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mymap"), mapOptions);

    map.mapTypes.set('Grayscale',oceanMapType);
    map.setMapTypeId('Grayscale');


    layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query:{
            select: 'unique_id',
            from: '3943497'
        },
        //map: map

    }); 


    layer2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({

        query:{
            select: 'unique_id',
            from: '3962564'         
        }
        //map: map

    }); 

    // may need to remove this line
    //layer1.setMap(map);

    }

    function old_toggleLayer(this_layer){
        if ( this_layer.getMap() ) {
            this_layer.setMap(null);
        }else{
            this_layer.setMap(map);
        }

    }

    function toggleLayer(this_layer){
        layer1.setMap(null);
        layer2.setMap(null);
        this_layer.setMap(map);

    }



</script>
```

Comment: Eric- Thank you! This looks great, but I implemented this code and it still isn't working. Can you take a look and see what I have done wrong? Is my map not a global variable? That's all I can think of...unless I have some other error that I'm unaware of. I'm still picking up the basics of javascript so I would not be surprised if I was missing something obvious to a seasoned JS vet. Here's my map in its current form: https://mywebspace.wisc.edu/csterling/web/cartel%20map/index.html

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.  Your map, and layer1 and layer2 must be globals. Plus the toggleMap() function should outside your onload() function. Finally, I changed the toggleMap() to first turn off both layers  since that seems to be your intent.

Comment: Notice: The Fusion Tables Layer in the Maps JavaScript API is deprecated as of December 3, 2018. The Fusion Tables Layer will be completely turned off on December 3, 2019, and will no longer be available after that date.

Answer (score 0):

See [Turning weather layer on/off combined with other selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335194/turning-weather-layer-on-off-combined-with-other-selections) ; I did this (with super help from Sean) for the weather/cloud layers. I suppose you can switch on/off all other layers the same way because I have the FT-layer active also. Just rip my code and tweak it.
Cheers! Frank

Comment: Frank- thank you. Is the link on that page the correct link? You said there's a weather/cloud layer, but 2 links are dead and the one at the  bottom seems to be more a cultural map than a weather/cloud map. Can you confirm that it's the right map?

Comment: This is the correct direct deeplink -> http://www.strahlen.org/map/map.htm ; have fun tweaking ;)