# Javascript for Google Fusion Table layers working but trying to tidy code

Tags: javascript, google-maps, checkbox, google-fusion-tables

I'm creating a map using Google Fusion Tables. It has several layers that are displayed or hidden depending on which checkboxes are ticked.

I created some code to turn the layers on/off, using a variable (layer10on) to keep track of whether each layer (layer10) was currently visible:

```
function toggleLayer10() { 
      if(layer10on) { layerl0.setOptions({map: null}); } 
      if(!layer10on) { layerl0.setOptions({map: map}); } 
      layer10on=!layer10on; 
}
```

...

```
<input type="checkbox" checked onchange="toggleLayer10();" />
```

This works okay, but I don't want to duplicate this code for each of the checkboxes / layers so I'm trying to pass parameters for which checkbox is ticked, and which layer that relates to, but it's not working:

```
function toggleLayer(layerToChange,checkboxID) {
    if(!document.getElementById(checkboxID).checked) {
        layerToChange.setOptions({map: null});
    }
    if(document.getElementById(checkboxID).checked) {
        layerToChange.setOptions({map: map});
    }
}
```

...

```
<input value="layer10" id="check10" type="checkbox" checked onchange="toggleLayer(this.value,this.id);" />
```

It's been years since I did any coding so any help to let me know where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

nicola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I showed an example toggleLayer in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759889/1211981) but it's not that concise. this_layer is the actual FT Layer which should be a global.  This checks whether the layer is visible or not.

```
function toggleLayer(this_layer)
{
   if( this_layer.getMap() ){
        this_layer.setMap(null);
   }else{
        this_layer.setMap(map);
   }
}
```

You need to have both your map as a global as well as your layers.  I think, but have not tested that your checkboxes should look like:

```
<input value="layer10" id="check10" type="checkbox" checked onchange="toggleLayer(layer10);" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that's much cleaner! Much appreciated.