# Show weather and clouds on Google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I make a weather application in Android which is showing current temperature and forecast based upon a JSON response. Now I want to add a weather map showing temperature and clouds, but I have no idea where to start.

It should look like in this question: [How to hide or display a Google Maps Layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318316/how-to-hide-or-display-a-google-maps-layer)

I have tried searching for a solution but didn't find anything.Please help me??

Comment: how to use this in android,please tell me any solution??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what given by Google
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#WeatherLayer

To show clouds use this Google API reference
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#CloudLayer

To show weather use this Google API reference
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#WeatherLayer

For Android developers looking for an example of how to use this api, please refer to the example given in the link below :-
http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?t=337

Comment: hello aurA thanks but i am looking the weather layer on google map in android please provide me any solution

Comment: I have edited the answer with An Android example. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: but dear Aura i already made the weather application now i want to add map which will display weather on google map,please tell me how to do this one.